# Image inside flex-item ignores max-height:100% in chrome and firefox - (works in safari)

Tags: css, flexbox

I want an image to fill either the width or height of the window-size/viewport.

**For a better understanding** of what i’m trying to do, [**i’ve created an example on codepen**](http://codepen.io/durchgemacht/pen/WvQvZJ) - please check out and resize the preview. **It works fine in safari** but chrome and firefox seems to have problems. The image ignores the max-height property and overflows the flex-item dimensions.

Any suggestions to get this work in chrome and firefox?

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.flex-item {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrEyQ.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that both the image and its containing block have

```css
max-height: 100%;
```

Instead, remove the `max` for the containing block:

```css
.flex-item {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.flex-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrEyQ.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

However, note that `.flex-item` will be centered inside `.flex-container`, but the image won't be centered inside `.flex-item`.

To fix that, you can use the [centering in the unknown](https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) technique (or alternatively, flexbox).

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}
.flex-item {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.flex-item:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrEyQ.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best answer I found about this topic.

Comment: Thank you for this! I was facing a similar issue with nested divs not respecting max-height in Chrome while Safari worked fine

Answer (score 0):

In Orio's solution the image is not vertical aligned in Safari, if the flex container' width is smaller than the width of the image: [Safari Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmzhT.png)

If I add

```
/*  Safari 7.1+ only */
_::-webkit-full-page-media, _:future, :root .flex-item  { height : auto; }
```

to the css the image is vertical centered in Safari.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9nmopzL5/10/)